# Return the value of 0 and 1 from database to No / Yes in a select box

Tags: php

In my database I have the column 'pe' with the value of 0 or 1.

0 equaling No/false and 1 equaling Yes/true.

How can I show the users the output of Yes or No instead of 0 or 1 based on there choice in the select box below?

Here is a picture of what the form currently looks like.
[Current Form](http://imgur.com/PK8rESC)

I would like the 1 to display Yes and the 0 to display No in the select box.
Just not sure how to do this since it's pulling the value from the database table.

I know an easy workaround would be to write "Please choose", instead of outputting the value, but I want the user(s) to see what they have already chosen.

**Here is my code snippet.**

```
<label for="pe">Would you like to make your Email public?</label>
<select name="pe">
<option value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->pe); ?>"><?php echo escape($user->data()->pe); ?></option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `<?php echo escape($user->data()->pe); ?>` is what returns `0` or `1`, simply use a ternary if statement:

```
<?php echo escape($user->data()->pe) == "1" ? "Yes" : "No"; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you that totally worked and was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$user->data()->pe` has the value 0 or 1
You can place the selected attribute on the option with that value.

```
<option value="1"<?php echo ($user->data()->pe == 1)?' selected':''; ?>>Yes</option>
<option value="0"<?php echo ($user->data()->pe == 0)?' selected':''; ?>>No</option>
```

Comment: That also worked very well. Thank you for showing me this method as well. Didn't realize there were a couple ways to do this.